# Continuous and one-one function that is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

[image]

Actually option 2 is  given as answer.So,other options are incorrect.I got an counter example for other options that they are not true.But I am unable to find a counter example to show option 4 is incorrect.

That is ,I need a continuous and one-one function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is not unbounded i.e. bounded.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Use the integral of a function whose integral over $\mathbb R$ is finite : like $e^{-|x|}$. Think about $f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t e^{-|u|}du$.

Comment: what is the counter example for 3rd option?

Comment: U can try $f(x)=e^x+2$ or $f(x)=e^x+a$ for any $a>1$ this is continuous  and will be one one too since $e^x$ is one one.

Answer (score 4):

Take e.g. the inverse tangent function $\arctan$.
It is injective and defined on the entire real number line but its range is $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.